# How to get the class name if only knowing the object pointer?

Tags: .net, windows, windbg, sos

We can get the method table and EEClass if we know the object pointer in .Net managed code. Based on that, but how the Windbg with SOS to get the object name? Just curious.

Comment: The SOS extension gets the object name from undocumented DAC (Data Access) APIs in mscordacwks.dll. Since the runtime is now open source, you can find more details if you dig into the code on GitHub. I'm posting this as a comment, because it would be more helpful if I could explain exactly where to find tho code. I have not yet looked at the code on GitHub.

Comment: @SteveJohnson: I tried to find it on Github and failed. Mybe I should get a local copy instead of browsing it in the Internet. Do you often need to read SOS code when you implement SOSEX?